# Camera rotation inverted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have come back to C# from JavaScript and am making a first person shooter game I am trying to get my camera to work it is inverted I have tried looking at tutorials switching transform.eulerAngles to quaternion and it didn't seem to work with not inverting my mouse. Anyways here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float characterSpeed = 5.0f;
  private float mouseX = 0.0f;
  private float mouseY = 0.0f;
  private float horizontalSpeed = 1.0f;
  private float verticalSpeed = 1.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
   if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * characterSpeed * Time.deltaTime);}
        
  
  
   if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * characterSpeed * Time.deltaTime);}
   
  
  
  
   if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * characterSpeed * Time.deltaTime);}
   
    
    
    
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
            transform.Translate(Vector3.back * characterSpeed * Time.deltaTime);}
    
    
    
    mouseX += horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    mouseY += verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0.0f);
    
    
    
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what exactly do you mean is inverted? What about simply invert according value (`-=`) ?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the params in eulerAngles looks incorrect.

`mouseX` should be rotating around the y axis.
`mouseY` should be rotating around the x axis.

In addition to this, you should invert the mouseY value.
The result of this inversion: moving the mouse up rotates in an upward direction.

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-mouseY, mouseX, 0.0f);
```